# Styling elements to design

Tags: html, css

(see attached image for reference) I want to style an element to have an image on the left and text on the right, with the text vertically aligned in the middle. I am VERY inexperienced with CSS and don't know where to begin. I have tried looking online but the issue is that I'm not sure what to search for.

Here's the HTML I have in place currently:

```
<div class="flex w-full h-screen items-center justify-center text-center" id="app">
        <div style="border-color: #8FC8E7; background-color: #F5F5F9;"
             @dragover="dragover"
             @dragleave="dragleave"
             @drop="drop">

            <input type="file"
                   multiple name="fields[assetsFieldHandle][]"
                   id="assetsFieldHandle"
                   class="w-px h-px opacity-0 overflow-hidden absolute ajaxFileUpload"
                   style="visibility: hidden"
                   @change="onChange"
                   ref="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" />

            <label for="assetsFieldHandle"
                   class="block cursor-pointer"
                   style="color: #4E5359">
                <div>
                    Drag and drop an image into this box, or <span style="color: #65B3DD;">click here</span> to select a file.
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction - I'm not looking for someone to just write out the CSS for me, I want to be able to understand what's done and why, so if anyone could assist me in what to google for, or point me to somewhere I can read up on how to do this specifically, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: You should use flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   background-color: DodgerBlue;
   border-radius: 10px; 
 }

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-container > p{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <p>A Flexible Layout must have a parent element with the property set to</p> 
</div>
```

We are creating a flex container, by using `display:flex`. This container contains a div and p as flex items. You will have to replace div with img and `border-radius: 10px;` will help you get rounded corners.

`display: flex; align-items: center;` helps you vertically center the element.

Comment: To get it aligning vertically I used align-self: center instead, align-items weren't working for some reason. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: flex;` to the div in which the input is placed, and to change the `flex-direction: row;` so it will display them in row

A good article about flexbox is at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Using flex got me sorted, thank you very much for pointing me to that guide!